# creating csv simple double header

Tags: tables, longtable, csvsimple

I am trying to include to first two rows as headers. I would like to have the units `- - m m m` etc. on every page and another line below.

I am not an advanced user of [csvsimple](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple), and I have not been able to find answers in the manual.

First page looks like this:

[image: first]

And the second:

[image: second]

I have already sorted out the problem of having latex symbols such as \delta.

Also, the other problem I am facing is that I cannot get the header to display on every page.

```
 \begin{longtable}{lllllllllll}
   \caption{Database of Ropax Ships.}\\
    \toprule
    \csvreader[
        head=false,
        late after line=\\,
        filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{1},
        ]{data_appendix.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \toprule
        \csvreader[
        head=false,
        late after line=\\,
        filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{1},
        ]{data_appendix.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    \csvreader[
        head=false,
        late after line=\\,
        filter not equal={\thecsvinputline}{1},
        ]{data_appendix.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
\end{longtable}
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please next time add an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you gave no MWE, so in parts I can only guess, but the main culprit here is to use the first two csv-lines in your headers for longtable and omit the first two csv-lines displaying the data.

Use the following code for the `\endfirsthead`:

```
\csvreader[%
    head=false,
    late after line=\\,
    filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{1},
    ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
\csvreader[% <====================================================== added
    head=false,
    late after line=\\,
    filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{2}, % <========================= line 2
    ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
\midrule
\endfirsthead
```

and for the `\endhead`:

```
\toprule
    \csvreader[
    head=false,
    late after line=\\,
    filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{1},
    ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
    \csvreader[% <================================================== added 
    head=false,
    late after line=\\,
    filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{2}, % <========================= line 2
    ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
\midrule
\endhead
```

The added lines with `\csvreader` print the second line with units to your table headers.

To print the complete table we only have to start printing with line 3 (line `filter test=\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{2},` checks if the current line number is more than 2):

```
\csvreader[%
    head=false,
    late after line=\\,
    filter test=\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{2},
    ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
```

So with the following complete mwe (please see that the headers need work you have already done, please use your not showed code):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Vessel Name , Year, LOA  , LBP  , B  , T   , D  , DUP  , Delta
-           , -   , m    , m    , m  , m   , m  , m    , t
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
Abel Matutes, 2010, 187  , 177  , 26.2, 6  , 9.2, 14.54, -
Aretousa    , 1995, 177.3, 166.4, 27  , 6.3, 9.1, 20.05, -
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lllllllllll}
   \caption{Database of Ropax Ships.}\\
    \toprule
    \csvreader[%
        head=false,
        late after line=\\,
        filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{1},
        ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
    \csvreader[% <====================================================== added
        head=false,
        late after line=\\,
        filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{2}, % <========================= line 2
        ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \toprule
        \csvreader[
        head=false,
        late after line=\\,
        filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{1},
        ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
        \csvreader[% <================================================== added 
        head=false,
        late after line=\\,
        filter equal={\thecsvinputline}{2}, % <========================= line 2
        ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    \csvreader[%
        head=false,
        late after line=\\,
        filter test=\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{2},
        ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting page 1]

shows the csv-lines 1 and 2 as table headers and starts the table content with line 3, and for the second page you get also showed lines 1 and 2 as header as wished:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! I am sorry for providing MWE, I will keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: @KZ123 You are welcome!